# Lights running without disconnect switch

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

There is what looks like a disconnect before the meter for the outside lights, but it looks like it missing a switch? How are the lights running and how would we disconnect them for service?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That looks like where a main breaker goes, and the stuff in there looks like the damaged guts of a main breaker.  I supremely doubt this is for the outside lights.

This an extreme hazard being just like it is. I strongly recommend you get an electrician out to fix it before it burns someone's hand.  What's more, it appears that something that is supposed to be breaker-protected, *isn't*.  So the protection is gone, opening the possibility of a fire.

Comment: Get the power company to pull the meter. This is dangerous.

Comment: @JACK yeah, that's why the words "get/hire an electrician" parted my lips.  That's the second time this year!

Comment: We don't hear you say that  very often.  Last week you told someone to get a handyman to change an outlet...  Sometimes ya gotta bite  the bullet.. (or bite your tongue).